# How do I derive the public key from a seedphrase using Python

Tags: python, solana.py

I'm trying to write a Python script to derive a public key from a Seed Phrase using Python.

My current code is the following.

```
def generate_solana_address_from_seed(seed_phrase):
    seed_phrase_str = ' '.join(seed_phrase)
    mnemo = Mnemonic("english")
    seed = mnemo.to_seed(seed_phrase_str)

    root = bip32utils.BIP32Key.fromEntropy(seed)
    child = (root.ChildKey(44 + bip32utils.BIP32_HARDEN)
             .ChildKey(501 + bip32utils.BIP32_HARDEN)
             .ChildKey(0 + bip32utils.BIP32_HARDEN)
             .ChildKey(0)
             .ChildKey(0))

    private_key = bytes(child.PrivateKey()) + bytes(child.PublicKey())

    keypair = Keypair.from_bytes(private_key)

    return str(keypair.pubkey())


test_address = generate_solana_address_from_seed(seed_phrase)
if test_address == known_public_address:
    print("\n\tMatch found")
else:
    print("No match")
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Solana-Wallet\v3.py", line 40, in <module>
    test_address = generate_solana_address_from_seed(seed_phrase)
  File "E:\Solana-Wallet\v3.py", line 35, in generate_solana_address_from_seed
    keypair = Keypair.from_bytes(private_key)
ValueError: expected a sequence of length 64 (got 65)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `Keypair.from_seed_phrase_and_passphrase`:

```
from pybip39 import Mnemonic
from solders.keypair import Keypair
mnemonic = Mnemonic()
passphrase = "42"
keypair = Keypair.from_seed_phrase_and_passphrase(mnemonic.phrase, passphrase)
public_key = keypair.pubkey()
```

Edit: in your comment you mention bip32 keypairs. This is how you do those:

```
from solders.keypair import Keypair
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
seed_bytes = bytes([0] * 64)
account_index = 0
derivation_path = f"m/44'/501'/0'/{account_index}'"
from_seed = Keypair.from_seed_and_derivation_path(seed_bytes, derivation_path)
```

Comment: what is phrase or passphrase in this context? and what about bip32 having infinite addresses?